# Condensation of Singularities, Principle of Uniform Boundedness

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces, baire-category

Let $X$, $Y$ be Banach spaces and $\{T_{j,k} : j,k \in\Bbb N\}$ be bounded linear maps from $X$ to $Y$. Suppose that for each $k$ there exists $x\in X$ such that $\sup\{\lVert T_{j,k} x\rVert : j \in\Bbb N\} =+\infty$. Then there is an $x$  such that $\sup\{\lVert T_{j,k} x\rVert : j \in\Bbb N\} =+ \infty$ for all $k$.

How can i argue by contradiction, and apply Baire categories theorem to

$$ F_{k,n}=\bigcap_{j\in \mathbb{N}} \{x\in X , \lVert T_{j,k} (x)\rVert_Y \leq n\}  $$

Answer (score 3):

So 
\begin{align*}
X=\bigcup_{k,n}F_{k,n},
\end{align*}
and each $F_{k,n}$ is closed, so by Baire Theorem some $k,n$ are such that $F_{k,n}^{\circ}\ne\emptyset$, so some $x\in X$, $\delta>0$ are such that
\begin{align*}
B_{\delta}(x)\subseteq F_{k,n}.
\end{align*}
For this $k$, we have by assumption some $x_{k}$ is such that $\sup\{\|T_{j,k}(x_{k})\|:j\in\mathbb{N}\}=\infty$.

However, we have
\begin{align*}
x-\dfrac{x_{k}}{\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1)}\in B_{\delta}(x),
\end{align*}
and that
\begin{align*}
x-\dfrac{x_{k}}{\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1)}+\dfrac{x_{k}}{\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1)}=x.
\end{align*}
We also have
\begin{align*}
\left\|T_{j,k}\left(x-\dfrac{x_{k}}{\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1)}\right)\right\|\leq n,
\end{align*}
and that
\begin{align*}
\|T_{j,k}(x)\|\leq n,
\end{align*}
so by triangle inequality, it follows that
\begin{align*}
\left\|T_{j,k}\left(\dfrac{x_{k}}{\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1)}\right)\right\|\leq 2n,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\|T_{j,k}(x_{k})\|\leq 2n\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1),
\end{align*}
varying $j\in\mathbb{N}$ arbitrarily, then 
\begin{align*}
\sup\{\|T_{j,k}(x_{k})\|: j\in\mathbb{N}\}\leq 2n\delta(\|x_{k}\|+1)<\infty,
\end{align*}
a contradiction.

Comment: Hello, I am reading this post. I understand how to get the contradiction, but does it imply $\text{Int}(F_{k,n})=\emptyset$ at last? At the begining, you claim $X=\bigcup_{k,n}F_{k,n}$. Why is this true? Or should I write $E=X\setminus O$, where $E$ the set that the sup-norm of the operators is infinity, and $O$ is the countable union of $F_{k,n}$? Here, $E$ is countable intersection of dense open sets, thus dense by Baire Category theorem. Thank you!

Comment: So you need to assume by contrary that for all $x\in X$, there is a $k$ such that $\sup_{j}\|T_{j,k}x\|<\infty$, the intersection inside the $F_{k,n}$ satisfies this condition.

Comment: The contradiction is not meant to contradict the statement that $F_{k,n}^{\circ}\ne\emptyset$, rather, it contradicts the $\sup$ thing.

Comment: yeah, I understand the point. My goal is to prove that the set involving infinity is dense in $X$, so I try to prove the interior is empty, which means $F_{k,n}$ is nowhere dense, i.e. it does not contain nonempty open sets. To prove this, I argue by contradiction to get the result. Then I use Baire Category theorem to conclude that the set involving infinity is dense in $X$, since complement of closed nonwhere dense sets is open and dense. This is what I think.