# The complement of the double countable union nowhere dense closed sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis, analysis

I am working on an exercise of functional analysis, which has been partially discussed here: [Condensation of Singularities, Principle of Uniform Boundedness](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3467897/condensation-of-singularities-principle-of-uniform-boundedness) and here: [The Principle of Condensation of Singularities](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/255223/the-principle-of-condensation-of-singularities).

I have finished most of it, but to conclude, I got stuck in topology. The following describes my question.

Say, I have proved that $Int(F_{k,n})=\varnothing$ for all $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $F_{k,n}$ is closed for all $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Consider the set defined by $$H_{k}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{k,n}\ \ \text{and}\ \ O:=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}H_{k}.$$

The space we are working with is a Banach space $V$, and the set I am considering is $E$ that satisfies $E=V\setminus O$.

I want to use  Baire category theorem to say that $E$ is dense in $V$.

So I start to argue that $O=\bigcup_{k,n=1}^{\infty}F_{k,n}$ is a countable union of closed dense sets, so that $E$ is a countable intersection of open dense sets. Therefore, the Baire category theorem implies that $E$ is dense.

However, I got confused about why $O$ is a countable union of closed dense sets. If we separate the double countable union, we will have $$O=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}\Bigg(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{k,n}\Bigg),$$ but $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{k,n}$ is not necessarily closed right? And in fact $H_{k}:=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}F_{k,n}$ is not necessarily dense anymore. So is this still safe to say $O$ is a countable union of closed dense sets?

Perhaps I am overthinking this and I believe there must be a way to prove the density of $E$ in $V$. Please let me know if you think I should provide more functional setup of this question. But for now I want to keep it as concrete as possible.

Thank you so much!

Comment: guys, why downvote? I think I am asking a pretty important technical detail :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sets $F_{k,n}$ are far from being dense: if they have empty interiors, they are **nowhere** dense. It’s true that the sets $H_k$ may not be nowhere dense, but they **are** [meagre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meagre_set), and a countable union of meagre sets is meagre. Your set $E$ is therefore co-meagre and hence by the Baire category theorem dense in $V$.

Comment: yes, they should be nowhere dense. Thanks for pointing out the meagre :)

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: You’re welcome. (And don’t worry about the mental hiccup: we all have them occasionally.)

Comment: Thank you for the kind words :)

Answer (score 1):

The collection $\{F_{k,n}:k, n \geq 1\}$ is a countable collection of closed nowhere dense sets and $O$ is its union. (You can always arrange this family in a single sequence $(C_n)$).

Comment: could you should a little bit technical details about how to arrange this family in a single sequence $C_{n}$ so that $C_{n}$ is still closed nowhere dense?

Comment: @JacobsonRadical: There’s no reason to do so: just use the fact that the union of countably many countable sets is countable.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott you are right. I was dumb